# Calling an api endpoint from MAUI client gives System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, maui

My login endpoint works well when tested from swagger interface.
But when i call the same in maui client i get **System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).'**

Below is my call:

```
public SircApiService()
    {
        _httpClient = new() { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress) };
    }

    public async Task<Authresponse> Login(LoginRequest loginRequest)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/login", loginRequest);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            statusMessage = "Login successful";
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Authresponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            statusMessage = ex.Message;
            return default;
        }
    }
```

My API end point:

```
app.MapPost("/login", async (LoginDTO loginDTO, SIRCContext db) =>
{
    var user = await db.AspnetMemberships.Where(m => m.Email == loginDTO.email).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (user is null)
        return Results.NotFound("No such user here.");

    bool IsPasswordValid = user.Password == loginDTO.password;
    if (!IsPasswordValid) return Results.Unauthorized();

    //Generate access token
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Key"]));
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var roleIDs = db.VwAspnetUsersInRoles.Where(r => r.UserId == user.UserId).Select(m => m.RoleId).ToList();
    var userRoles = (from r in db.AspnetRoles where roleIDs.Contains(r.RoleId) select r.RoleName).ToList();
    //var claims = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

    var tokenClaims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid,user.UserId.ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti,Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email,user.Email)
    }.Union(userRoles.Select(r => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, r)));

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
        audience: builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
        claims: tokenClaims,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:DurationInMinutes"])),
        signingCredentials: credentials
        );
    var accessToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    var response = new AuthResponseDTO
    {
        UserId = user.UserId.ToString(),
        username = user.Email,
        token = accessToken
    };
    return Results.Ok(response);
}).AllowAnonymous();
```

Comment: PostAsJsonAsync needs a full url not just the /login

Comment: Hi @IsidorosMoulas, The _httpClient object has a base address of the api that concatenates to the '/login'

Comment: does `LoginRequest`  match `LoginDTO`?

Comment: Thank you @Jason. You are always the magician!